# Failing backup, Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: backup

after I installed Ubuntu 12.04, my automatic backup hasn't been working. I get that it failed with an unknown error, and the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1411, in <module>
        with_tempdir(main)

    File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1404, in with_tempdir
        fn()

    File "/usr/bin/duplicity", line 1255, in main
        action = commandline.ProcessCommandLine(sys.argv[1:])

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/commandline.py", line 999, in ProcessCommandLine
        globals.backend = backend.get_backend(args[0])

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 158, in get_backend
        return _backends[pu.scheme](pu)

    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/_boto_single.py", line 49, in __init__
        import boto

    ImportError: No module named boto
```

I haven't changed anything from 10.10. The specified backup location is my Amazon S3 account. I have tried to google this, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the boto package:

```
sudo apt-get install python-boto
```

Comment: I installed and it still didn't work, I found a bug on launchpad about this. Apparently this is only trigger after verifying the backup. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity/+bug/1159516